# What does 'fifteen' mean in 'fifteen of the seventy-five-thousand-pound prize money'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, numbers, numerals

I have read an article from IELTS:

> We invested fifteen of the seventy-five-thousand-pound prize money to help secure our future.

Does the 'fifteen' in the sentence mean 15% or fifteen thousand pound?

Comment: It's ambiguous.  The logical interpretation from the context is 15,000 out of 75,000 (=20%).  But it could mean 15 out of 75,000 (=0.02%)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means £15000. In the sentence 75000 possesses fifteen so it can't be percentage. Now, being £15000 is only assumed, it could literally mean only £15 but that's unlikely since they're talking about securing their future.

Comment: Nice point about the context. In a similar way, if I said, "We spent fifteen of the 75,000 prize money so we could buy lunch," I'd likely be talking about £15, not £15000.